# Automatically fill row with value based on inserted id

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert, database-trigger

I have a table where the user is able to insert the ID of a Node that corresponds to a title elsewhere in the database. I want this tile to be automatically inserted into the row after the user has chosen the id.

This is my table: [image]

I need to have the "SommerhusNavn" column be automatically filled with values based on the "SommerhusId" inserted.

I am using a third party to handle the CRUD functionality, where the user picks the ID from a dropdown. I already know in which table the title for the ID is located, I'm just not sure how to fill the row with the insert statement. Would I need to run a separate query for this to happen?

Edit:Solution

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[BlokeredePerioderInsert]
ON  dbo.BlokeredePerioder
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN   
SET NOCOUNT ON;

UPDATE BlokeredePerioder SET SommerhusNavn = text FROM umbracoNode AS umbNode
where SommerhusId = umbNode.id

END
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to run additional `UPDATE` query. Let's assume that you have the `TitlesTable`, with columns `ID` and `Title`. Then it should look like:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET SommerhusNavn = Title FROM TitlesTable AS A
WHERE SommerhusId = A.ID
  AND SommerhusNavn IS NOT NULL --not necessary
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try!

Comment: I created a trigger with the update code you provided and that worked for me. I'll insert the solution in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps i'm not understanding, but why can't you use send the value across in the initial update?

Can you use a trigger on the database side?

Alternatively, you'll need to send a update across, following the insert.